# Why "enableBuildCache=true" doesn't work for my Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, gradlew

I notice it's a little different between I with my colleague to compile a same project -- the build time. I build a project by 1m30s, but he just need 20s. Our computer and `vm.options` both are same.

I notice 'gradle build cache' maybe is a point for this problem. So, I add `android.enableBuildCache=true` to `gradle.properties`, it's doesn't work(I know it's default `true`). Then, I change it to `android.enableBuildCache=false`. Some interesting things happen, the build speed doesn't change! I'm already allow Android Studio to 'Access Full Disk', I notice in `./gradlew --profile`, it's compile my code again after I change only one line code.

What can I do to make my 'gradle build cache' work normally?

[image: my gradle profile]

Android Studio Version: 3.6.1, my computer info as below:
[image: my computer info]